# trouble understanding rollback jdbc

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, rollback

When I execute the code below the entry/row with an user_id of 8 is deleted although I have called the `rollback()` method.

What I am expecting is the row with user_id=8 to be present in the table after the program executes.

What am I missing here?

```
public class delete_record  {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException{

    Connection conobj=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root","");
    conobj.setAutoCommit(false);

    Statement stmt= conobj.createStatement();

    stmt.executeUpdate("delete from testtab where user_id=8");

    conobj.rollback();

    } 
}
```

Comment: Are you in InnoDB mode ?

Comment: @Arnaud thankyou so much your comment pointed me to the right direction. I didnt know about InnoDB and MyISAM thing before asking this question and after changing the engine to InnoDB it works perfectly as expected! Thanks!